# HDInsight and Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, storage, azure-hdinsight

I'm wondering if Azure Table Storage can be used as a data source for Map/Reduce tasks on HDInsight cluster.

Obviously data can be exported from Table Storage into a flat file and then imported into HDInsight, but would be good to have more seamless integration.

Comment: According to this thread it can't be used directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106040/can-we-use-hdinsight-service-for-ats

Answer (score 1):

This article was published by Mostafa Elhemali from the HDInsight team: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mostlytrue/archive/2014/04/04/analyzing-azure-table-storage-data-with-hdinsight.aspx