# Can we use HDInsight Service for ATS?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-hdinsight

We have a logging system called as Xtrace. We use this system to dump logs, exceptions, traces etc. in SQL Azure database. Ops team then uses this data for debugging, SCOM purpose. Considering the 150 GB limitation that SQL Azure has we are thinking of using HDInsight (Big Data) Service.

1. If we dump the data in Azure Table Storage, will HDInsight Service work against ATS?
2. Or it will work only against the blob storage, which means the log records need to be created as files on blob storage?

   1. Last question. Considering the scenario I explained above, is it a good candidate to use HDInsight Service?

Answer (score 1):

HDInsight is going to consume content from HDFS, or from blob storage mapped to HDFS via Azure Storage Vault (ASV), which effectively provides an HDFS layer on top of blob storage. The latter is the recommended approach, since you can have a significant amount of content written to blob storage, and this maps nicely into a file system that can be consumed by your HDInsight job later. This would work great for things like logs/traces. Imagine writing hourly logs to separate blobs within a particular container. You'd then have your HDInsight cluster created, attached to the same storage account. It then becomes very straightforward to specify your input directory, which is mapped to files inside your designated storage container, and off you go.

You can also store data in Windows Azure SQL DB (legacy naming: "SQL Azure"), and use a tool called **Sqoop** to import data straight from SQL DB into HDFS for processing. However, you'll have the 150GB limit you mentioned in your question.

There's no built-in mapping from Table Storage to HDFS; you'd need to create some type of converter to read from Table Storage and write to text files for processing (but I think writing directly to text files will be more efficient, skipping the need for doing a bulk read/write in preparation for your HDInsight processing). Of course, if you're doing non-HDInsight queries on your logging data, then it may indeed be beneficial to store initially to Table Storage, then extracting the specific data you need whenever launching your HDInsight jobs.

There's some [HDInsight documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/hdinsight/) up on the Azure Portal that provides more detail around HDFS + Azure Storage Vault.

Comment: this article was published a few weeks ago for table storage: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mostlytrue/archive/2014/04/04/analyzing-azure-table-storage-data-with-hdinsight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is sligthly misleading in regard to the Azure Table Storage part. It is not necessary to first write ATS contents to text files and then process the text files. Instead a standard Hadoop InputFormat or Hive StorageHandler can be written, that reads directly from ATS. There are at least 2 implementations available at this point in time:

- [ATS InputFormat and Hive StorageHandler written by an MS employee](https://github.com/mooso/azure-tables-hadoop)
- [ATS Hive StorageHandler written by Simon Ball](https://github.com/simonellistonball/hive-azuretables)

Comment: The date of the question is irrelevant if it pops up in searches for the subject, which it did.